# Need to make a bar plot with two columns of data from a data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to make a bar graph of two columns from a data.frame side by side of each other. I have tried:

```
barplot(data.frame$data1, data.frame$data2, data=data.frame)

here is data:   
   Neutral Emotional
1   0.790   1.6400
2   0.051   0.0880
3   0.891   2.7200
4   0.430   1.1800
5   -0.009  -0.6000
```

but it makes a ton of bars instead of just two. I am trying to have two bars, one with neutral one with emotional and error bars representing SEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to achieve this result are discussed [in this guide](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar/). Note that they recommend `ggplot2` over `barplot`.

To get the chart with error bars for standard error of the mean:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val), 
            SD = sd(Val), 
            SE = SD/sqrt(n())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, Mean)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SE, 
                    ymax = Mean + SE),
                width = 0.5)
```

Result:

[image]

**However**: note that so-called "dynamite plots" are not well-regarded by data visualisation experts. For small numbers of samples, it is better to show the range using `geom_boxplot` or `geom_jitter`.

Boxplot:

```
data.frame %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, Val)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Jitter with mean:

```
data.frame %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, Val)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", 
               fun.y = mean, 
               fun.ymax = mean, 
               fun.ymin = mean, 
               color = "red", 
               width = 0.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to `gather` into 'long' format and then use `geom_bar` from `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
gather(df1) %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x = key, y = value)) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

---

If we also need an error bar, then

```
gather(df1) %>% 
     ggplot(., aes(x = key, y = value)) +
         stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar") + 
         stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar")
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Neutral = c(0.79, 0.051, 0.891, 0.43), Emotional = c(1.64, 
0.088, 2.72, 1.18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: How can I make the y axis value to scale? Making it go up to 0.891 for neutral and 2.72 for emotional?

Comment: You can use `ylim()`. But I think the axis scale should reflect the summarised values, not the individual points. Of course this is not an issue if boxplots or jitter are used.